# Is there a result of voting up a comment?

Tags: support

It doesn't seem to accrue reputation points for the recipient, so I wonder if it does anything more than increment a score for the comment itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Pundit](https://serverfault.com/badges/68/pundit) badge is about it really.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, that's all it does. No rep is gained for upvoting. Well, ok it is used in a badge calculation, but that's about it.

Answer (score 2):

It is also a way to agree with a comment rather than saying "OMFGWTFBBQ! I like ponies too!" (or the equivalent).

Comment: Upvoting basically means you agree or significantly approve of the content of a comment. There's no way to disagree with a comment, hence the lack of reputation possibilities attached to comments.